# Prestashop new theme collides with default theme

Tags: themes, prestashop

I am currently pulling hair out of my head, as I have spent over 7 hours on this. Here's the problem

I am setting prestashop on my free hosting and trying to install new theme (freshmarket). Everything installs just fine but effects are not working. There are some elements of the default-bootstrap style I cant remove, and I've tried many ways (deleting modules, deleting files directly from ftp folders etc etc) Logo stays the same, menu stays the same, green bar isn't there, and even photos of sample products are from default theme.

here is the url http://nasiona.cba.pl/ 
and it should look like this www.templatemela.com/demo/PRS050107/

I checked version description of theme and it says it would work on prestashop 1.6.1.4 (which is installed on the server).

@Egg, yes, you're right, sorry.

as for your question - my settings http://i63.tinypic.com/2yvjwye.png (i hope you can see anything cause I wanted to show it all)

Comment: If you are looking for a help from Prestashop developers, please watch your language about it ;) What are you cache settings (Backoffice > Advanced parameters > Performance)?

Comment: my settings http://i63.tinypic.com/2yvjwye.png (i hope you can see anything cause I wanted to show it all)

Comment: I see you have modified your site, maybe you have not uploaded all theme files? I. e. the green backgound for the top menu is defined with the file `/themes/PRS050107/css/modules/blocktopmenu/css/superfish-modified.css`. Do you have this file on place?

Comment: Or just install a fresh Prestashop and reinstal this theme one more time. For you have customised it now.

Comment: ok, so I managed to get rid of link section from default theme but still can't have this green bar with links from template demo. Any thoughts? maybe it must be integrated with standard prestashop module? I dont have any ideas left

Comment: ok, I did it. turns out you need to use default module to manage menu bar. everything works

Comment: Yes, the default module but custom CSS ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Disable the cache** (you can refer to Prestashop help [http://doc.prestashop.com](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Setting+Up+Your+Local+Development+Environment#SettingUpYourLocalDevelopmentEnvironment-DisablingthecacheandforcingSmartycompilation)), reload the page with Ctrl + F5 (clear your browser cache) and check.

[image: Cache disabled.]
[image: Cache disabled.]

Comment: thank you for your answer, sadly it doesnt work. I am going to keep trying anyway, I've lost too much time and nerves to just drop it off :D